# BufferedWriter cannot restart

Tags: java, csv

I am using the java bufferedwriter to write to a csv file. Everytime I run the program, the data is being written correctly to the file but the data from previous runs are still found in the file.

I need the file to be empty each time before the bufferwriter starts again.

I tried using the flush() method already.

Anyone has some suggestions? The following is my code;

```
if (!file.exists()) {
file.createNewFile();
                }

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(),true);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.newLine();
bw.append(" " + epochs);
bw.append(",");
bw.append("badfact" + badfacts);
bw.flush();
bw.close();
}
```

Comment: `flush()` only pushes the data(if any exists) out of the `BufferedWriter`.

Comment: You should accept an answer to let others know what worked for you. It is a good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following,

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), false);
```

The second parameter in `FileWriter` constructor is for appending.

If it is `true` then data will be appended to the previous data in the file. If `false` then the previous data will be removed and new data will be written.

Comment: thanks for your help. I have tried your suggestion and it works as it does not append anymore but then i get only one row of data... i used to have around 350 rows of data and now it only writes the last string it is supposed to write ...

Answer (score 2):

As @GPRathour answered the second parameter is for appending to file.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(),true);
```

I just wanted to add that the 1 argument call is equivalent to `append = false`  so you can use this also.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append)
```

Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name with a boolean indicating whether or not to append the data written.

**Parameters:**
    **fileName** - String The system-dependent filename.
    **append** - boolean if **true**, then data will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.

[refer java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)

Modified Code: you have to give false value for `append` parameter.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(),false);
```